# Magento 2 Remove Subtotal from order email

Tags: magento2, email-templates, order-email

How can i remove Subtotal from order email in Magento 2.3.4?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in case anyone need it.

You can override /public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/totals.phtml in your theme /public_html/app/design/frontend/[theme]/Magento_Sales/templates/order/totals.phtml

and add `<?php if($_code == 'subtotal'){ continue; } ?>`

after `<?php foreach ($block->getTotals() as $_code => $_total) : ?>`
[image]